# How to use "Got It" Button in Material ShowcaseView Library?

Tags: android, showcaseview

I am using Material ShowcaseView https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView.
Now I am getting the view in my app by adding **transparency to the PULL DOWN TO REFRESH Activity**. But when I click the **"Got It"** in **Image1**,**the transparency was gone but the image(Arrow) which is marked as Red in Image2 is there.**

[image]    [image]

**I need to go the next activity when I click "Got it" or I need to replace this "Got it" text into the Button View.How do I do this? Please help me...**

I need the output like this..Button over the transparent layer.

[image]

Comment: in matrial showcase method `setDismissText("GOT IT")` try to use setDismissButton and then check if it works or not

Comment: No..It didnt work @Abhishek

Comment: may be library doesnot support it you can use many other libraries instead of that

Comment: Okay..I have added another screenshot that I expect Button option Like this. Can you suggest any other library which have this Button Clicking option?

Comment: have you tried tourguide?

Comment: Yes I am trying to implement it.Working on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an `onClickListener` method to the dismiss button according to this:

https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/uk/co/deanwild/materialshowcaseviewsample/SequenceExample.java

As you can see he uses:

```
mButtonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_one);
mButtonOne.setOnClickListener(this);

mButtonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_two);
mButtonTwo.setOnClickListener(this);

mButtonThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_three);
mButtonThree.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and then on the Listener method:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_one) {
            //presentShowcaseSequence();
            Intent intent  = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivityIntent(intent);

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_reset) {

            MaterialShowcaseView.resetSingleUse(this, SHOWCASE_ID);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Showcase reset", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: I used intent instead of Toast in else if. When I tried to run my app,it directly goes to next activity & not showed the Showcaseview.

Comment: you have to actually `presentShowcaseSequence();` method for the first button and then for the second button you should use the Intent

Comment: But I am having only one image is there to click.

Comment: then present the showcase method in onCreate directly and then use the listener to go the next activity. Its hard for someone to understand without code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102061/discussion-between-parama-sudha-and-helldawg13).